# Old Computer Text Game Puzzles

Tags: pattern, cipher

I'm playing this old text adventure game for the computer.  It's a fantasy game based on magic and such.  In the game there are hints on how to progress the game.  I have solved a few, but these other ones are very challenging.  It looks like the author changes the methodology for each puzzle.  There was one that was reversed with an extra letter at the beginning of each word, there was a typical cryptogram, and there was one that was a phrase using jumbles, but had one of the letters missing.

I don't have much more than what I'm about to post.  In the game you look at things like statues and pools of water and you'll see a puzzle.  So far the room description has nothing to do with the puzzle.

Here's an example of one of the puzzles that I mostly solved.

HA-TC EN-ESA-EOP ORE-EF GUSI- XX-HE XXX-E-

CHANT .......... BEFORE USING   THE    KEY

If someone can find that missing word I'd be very happy.  But here are the real ones that I can't even get my mind around:

## 1:  ID- UPI- OZS-OMSY-PM -P P-YSOM Y-R FS--RT

## 2:  FEOAMUT WOTAQUOP JAGAROONI PISTOBBA

## 3:  D-TU U-F VO-OPX- TQF-M I-SF.

## 4:  HQOFOWY ASITPQNM IFQNPYTUVC QOTMAY GIOEM LOOPAS ASIT, ILLIADA FALGORIA SIMAJF. UNALOOP LA HEARTOY.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: While the room description may not have had anything to do with the previous puzzles, if each of these are solved differently, more information pertinent to the area, or environment, for the puzzles, may provide assistance to those attempting to help, if you have it. :)

Comment: Are the dashes in the words splitting the lines?  For example in #1 is P-YSOM one word or is it a two and four letter word?

Comment: @Aaron: would a link to a walkthrough be helpful?  I found two, although neither one specifies the solution to the cryptograms.  There is also a Let's Play on youtube.

Comment: LOOP in the fourth text could refer to POOL. You talked about pools of water...

Comment: @Khale_Kitha:  I really think it's mainly wordplay and letter arrangement in the puzzles themselves.  I'm afraid putting up the room descriptions (which each one is pretty long) would hurt more than help.

Comment: Oh, I figured.  I meant more of a small synopsis of them, unless you really think it would hurt finding the answers.  It looks, so far, though, as if you are right, so you can probably disregard the suggestion.

Comment: @LeppyR64:  I think the dashes are missing letters and I'm assuming the spacing is supposed to be preserved.

Comment: @fondor:  It could, and I saw that too.  But I just couldn't make the other words show up based on that pattern.  I'll see what I can do in that reference.

Comment: @DaphneB:  I did find that walkthrough.  It's actually where I found these puzzles.  lol!  I'm documenting the game as much as I can and I want to include these puzzles in that documentation.

Awesome job on those you solved!  I'll check out the one you mentioned at the end of your solution.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Khale_Kitha:  Good idea!  :)  There are rooms where special actions have to take place, and these are apparently clues to what the special actions should be.

For example, on the one that I have in my original post, you have to "chant" at a certain room and then put a key in a crevice.  As DaphneB pointed out, there is a walkthrough on YouTube.  Here's a link to the beginning of the series of videos.  Maybe it'll give a good background.  :)

You can skip to the 3 minute mark if you don't want to see the history.
[The Other Kyrandia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSBBy2QE-lw)

Comment: I miss The Legend of Kyrandia - had forgotten about it!

Comment: @Khale_Kitha:  Fun game, huh?  I've thought about it from time to time the last 25ish years since I've played it.

Comment: @Aaron I agree, I am saying that viewing your question on mobile I see a dash at the end of the line and then two more characters on the next line.  Is it actually two words on is it one in the game?

Comment: @LeppyR64:  I think all puzzles are supposed to be on a single line.  You're probably seeing it a little distorted because of the smaller screen of the mobile.

Comment: @Aaron I agree.  So is P-YSOM one word or two?  Same with I-SF in #3 is it one word or two?

Comment: Is it "P- YSOM" or "P-YSOM".  Is it "I-SF" or "I- SF"

Comment: @LeppyR64:  P-YSOM is one word.  And I-SF is one word too.  Khale_Kitha translated them below to be "obtain" and "here", respectively.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha: You're right!  Oops!  Sorry!   Yes, it was DaphneB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Number one decrypts to

> US- YOU- IMA-INAT-ON -O O-TAIN T-E ?A--E?
>  which I bet is USE YOUR IMAGINATION TO OBTAIN THE (DAGGER?) or whatever noun is in the room somewhere
>  There doesn't seem to be any pattern here.  I plugged it into a crypto-solver and messed around.  I got lucky because I noticed that YSOM and OMSY have the same letters, and then I got lucky because I tried TION for YSOM which is pretty close to the real thing.  After that it was just some switching back and forth.
>  Edited to add: it is based on a typewriter/computer keyboard.  Take the given letters and then shift once left.

Number three is

> go back one letter alphabetically
>  C-ST T-E UN-NOW- SPE-L H-RE
>  which I assume means CAST THE UNKNOWN SPELL HERE (and that makes the blank letters AHKNLE if that has any meaning

As to how I came to think of it:

> I guessed the three-letter word U-F was probably THE and noticed how I could get there.

I'll update this if I think of any of the others.

Comment: Awesome!  I'm not very good at puzzles like this.  You guys make it seem easy!  hehehehe

Answer (score 1):

Your missing word(s) is(are):

> OPEN SESAME

(This is the answer to the preamble question the OP asks - see comments)

Comment: Thanks!  They tricked me.  I thought it was one word.  Probably an error on the programmer's part.

Comment: Pity this is identical to another answer that was already on the puzzle, but deleted.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that is the correct answer? Answers without explanations are usually deleted.

Comment: In the description, before listing the other puzzles, I referred to one that I mostly solved but couldn't figure out what one word was.  The spacing has been correct in the other puzzles and I figured this one was too.

Turns out that this "one word" was really two and Jon Mark Perry figured it out.  The dashes are where "unknown" letters are.

EN-ESA-EOP  becomes  OPEN SESAME (by finding out the two missing letters were M and S).